# But var it is not for local variable?

Tags: javascript, closures

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/p7D6V/5/) is my code :

```
var markers={};
example();

function example() {
    var myFunct = function () {
        alert("hello");
    };

    markers["myIndex"] = myFunct; 
}

markers["myIndex"]();
```

as you can see, `myFunct` is "var" (so, when `example()` finish, it will be destroyed, because it is local). But in fact, accessing to `markers["myIndex"]()`, the function is referenced, and I can access to it. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, functions are objects just like other objects. When you do this:

```
var myFunct = function () {
    alert("hello");
};
```

...you're creating a function and assigning a *reference* to that function to the variable `myFunct`. Then when you do this:

```
markers["myIndex"] = myFunct;
```

...you're assigning another reference to that function to `markers["myIndex"]`. So regardless of anything else that might happen to the `myFunct` variable, because `markers["myIndex"]` still has a reference to the function, the function is kept in memory.

But *separately*, there's a more subtle misunderstanding in your question as well: You've said:

> `myFunct` is "var" (so, when `example()` finish, it will be destroyed, because it is local)

That's not true in JavaScript. In JavaScript, local variables are actually properties of a hidden object, called (deep breath) the *variable binding object* of the *execution context* (let's just call it the "variable object"). This object is associated with the particular call to `example`: It's created when the call to `example` is executed. Now, in the normal course of things, when `example` returns, if nothing has any outstanding reference to the variable object, then you're quite correct that it is eligible for garbage collection. But in your case, something *does* have a reference to the variable object: The function you created. When you create a function, it receives an implicit reference to the variable object for the context in which it was created, and it *keeps* that reference for as long as the function exists. So even though the function you're creating doesn't refer to anything in the variable object for the call to `example`, it has that reference to it nevertheless, and the variable object cannot be reclaimed until or unless nothing has a reference to the function anymore. This is how *closures* work. The foregoing text notwithstanding, [closures are not complicated](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html), they're really, really simple when you understand how they work.

(I'll just note here that some JavaScript engines introspect the code sufficiently that they can reclaim variable objects even when there are outstanding closures that refer to them. Specifically, if the closures [functions] don't actually use any of the variable object's properties, and they don't use `eval`, then the engine *may* be able to release the variable object. Chrome's V8 engine does this, for instance. But that's a runtime optimization; the *concept* is as described above.)

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't work the way you expect it to. In other words, when `example()` finishes, `myFunct` will not be destroyed because there is still a reference to that function in a variable from an outer scope, `markers`.

The only way it would be 'destroyed' is if nothing else referenced it at the end of `example()` or if only variables with equal or lower scope referenced it, provided those variables also followed the same rules and were not referenced from outer variables.

Comment: It does change scope (of the variable). But yes, the object doesn't care whether there's two references to it or one.

Comment: right, `var` makes it so that by default the variable won't be visible in outer scopes, but you can assign that variable to outer scopes if you want.

Comment: *"you can assign that variable to outer scopes if you want"* You can assign the *value* of the variable to variables in outer scopes (or inner scopes, for that matter). Not the variable itself. Normally that kind of distinction isn't all that important in casual conversation, but it's relevant to the question in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have assigned it to the global variable `markers` from within your `example` function.

Answer (score 1):

you're assigning a reference to the function object to a higher scope (if not global scope) object. So while `myFunct` would be garbage collected, the function is not, since there is another reference to it in the markers object.

Answer (score 1):

A reference from `var myFunct` to the actual function object (`function() { ... }`) will indeed be destroyed. But the object itself will not, as it is referenced by a `markers` field. Once there are no live references to the function object from live JS objects, this function object will be eligible for garbage collection.